# Call child method from parent, when child is a template

Tags: c++, templates

I have this college project where I have to create a BinarySearchTree class using templates. We have to read a file and create the tree depending of the data type in the file. I made a parent class for the tree called BST so I can use the tree without giving it a class type.

```
class BST{
    public:
        BST();
        ~BST();
}
```

And the tree

```
template <class T> class BinarySearchTree : public BST{
    public:
        void add(T val);
}
```

And I wanted to do this:

```
BST tree = BinarySearchTree<int>(); //just an example, it can be of any type
tree.add(5); //doesn't work
```

How can I call "add" from BST without giving a specific variable type?

Comment: Polymorphism requires indirection via pointer or reference. [A decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would have told you as much.

Comment: So I have to use pointers? Like BST* tree = new BinarySearchTree<int>(); ??

Comment: Why don't you want to use BST without a class type? Also, you can use typename instead of class if you want primitive type too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a virtual method in the class BST and also make BST a template.

```
virtual void add(T val) = 0;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't wanted to do, I cant make it a template, because I don't have the variable type

Comment: @Juanky I don't know if you can.

Answer (score -1):

Use CRTP(Curiously Reccursive/Reccuring Template Pattern) and Concept Pattern.

https://qiita.com/Riyaaaa_a/items/a9af401520f238f45b80

This is written in Japanese, however, it's interesting!